# How to extract a column from this generated table?

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I have this generated table and I want to parse it with Mojo::DOM and extract the columns 'Username' and 'No. comments' in 2 different arrays. I can't figure out how to do that. Can you help me? Or maybe some guidance to some documentation. Thanks a lot guys!

```
#           <table class="table table-hover">
#             <thead>
#               <th>Username</th>
#               <th>Tip</th>
#               <th>Last login</th>
#               <th>No. comments</th>
#             </thead>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user8"
#                     >user8</a></td>
#                   <td>level2</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2019-09-26 00:00:00</td>
#                   <td>0</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user9"
#                     >user9</a></td>
#                   <td>level2</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2019-09-26 00:00:00</td>
#                   <td>0</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user11"
#                     >user11</a></td>
#                   <td>level2</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2019-09-26 00:00:00</td>
#                   <td>0</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user1"
#                     >user1</a></td>
#                   <td>level1</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2020-02-28 10:43:09</td>
#                   <td>23</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user2"
#                     >user2</a></td>
#                   <td>level1</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2020-02-28 10:43:10</td>
#                   <td>2</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user3"
#                     >user3</a></td>
#                   <td>level1</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2020-02-28 10:43:10</td>
#                   <td>3</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user4"
#                     >user4</a></td>
#                   <td>level1</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2020-02-28 10:43:11</td>
#                   <td>4</td>
#                 </tr>
#                 <tr>
#                   <td><a href="/user/user5"
#                     >user5</a></td>
#                   <td>level1</td>
#                   <td class="dateTime">2020-02-28 10:43:11</td>
#                   <td>5</td>
#                 </tr>
```

Comment: You can use CSS selectors or xpath in Mojo::DOM. Go via the position of the column. It's always the 1st and the last column.

Comment: Next time, show us what you've tried so far please.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Mojo::DOM by iterating over the cells.

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my (@usernames, @comment_count);
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->parse(do { local $/ = undef; <DATA>});
$dom->find('table.table tr')->each(sub {
    my $cells = $_->find('td');

    push @usernames, $cells->[0]->all_text; # because there's an <a> inside
    push @comment_count, $cells->[-1]->text;
});

__DATA__
...
```

This will create these two arrays with your example data.

```
[
    [0] "user8",
    [1] "user9",
    [2] "user11",
    [3] "user1",
    [4] "user2",
    [5] "user3",
    [6] "user4",
    [7] "user5"
]
[
    [0] 0,
    [1] 0,
    [2] 0,
    [3] 23,
    [4] 2,
    [5] 3,
    [6] 4,
    [7] 5
]
```

The code works by finding and iterating over all the table rows, and accessing the data inside the cells by their position, then grabbing their text nodes.

I got to this solution by looking at https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM for finding the right nodes, and https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Collection for checking how to iterate the results. Ultimately all parsers work the similarly. If you understand the concept behind working on a tree structure, it doesn't really matter which implementation you use, it's all just looking up the right syntax then.

Comment: instead of <DATA>, there should be the name of my html file, right?

Comment: https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/HTML#parse - it works on strings actually, so not a file name. I tried passing in `\*DATA`, which would be a GLOB ref (similar to a `$fh` IO::Handle object), but that didn't work. So you should probably read the file first. You can do that like I did, after adding an `open`.

Comment: no, for what I want to do, I need to save the html code in a string type variable after I am doing the request for backend function. thanks again man

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] to learn how to accept answers that solve your problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: ok, I am sorry for being retarded, thanks a lot again for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: FWIW - Mojo::DOM's parse method takes decoded characters, and only that. You are expected to do the steps of [reading the file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::File#slurp) and then [decoding it from bytes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Util#decode) (usually UTF-8). [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#slurp,-slurp_raw,-slurp_utf8) or [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper#read_text($filename,-$encoding,-$crlf)) can do this in one step.

Comment: (DATA is already decoded, provided you had `use utf8;` or `use Mojo::Base` in the file.)

Answer (score 3):

> extract the columns 'Username' and 'No. comments' in 2 different arrays

This is almost certainly a bad idea. Storing linked data in two separate data structures is a recipe for disaster. Far better to store this data in an array of hashes.

Adapting the answer you've already received:

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my @users;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->parse(do { local $/ = undef; <DATA>});

$dom->find('table.table tr')->each(sub {
    my $cells = $_->find('td');

    my $user = {
      name          => $cells->[0]->all_text, # because there's an <a> inside
      comment_count => $cells->[-1]->text;
    };

    push @users, $user;
});

__DATA__
...
```

Comment: This looks vaguely familiar... ;)

Comment: @simbabque: As I said, "Adapting the answer you've already received". I know next to nothing about Mojolicious, so I had to rely on someone else to do the clever bit :-)

Comment: I wasn't complaining, in fact I agree with you :)